# Does ros_arduino_bridge support a gyro or imu?

Tags: ros, imu, gyro, ros-arduino-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros_arduino_bridge to operate an arduino-based robot and it works well both for odometry and motor driving.  However, I want to add a gyro to enable better calibration and also to then have the functionality of a turtlebot.  Then it is easy to add additional sensors such as a kinect.

I know that I could write stand-alone routines to feed the gyro data directly, but it is a hurdle to get a sufficient understanding of nav msgs and figure out the details of how to correctly publish that data.  Since ros_arduino_bridge does such a nice job with wheel odometry, I am hoping that there is a way to incorporate gyro data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70309/does-ros_arduino_bridge-support-a-gyro-or-imu?/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @dan - it shouldn't be that hard to add gyro support but (as the author of the ros_arduino_bridge package), I don't have the time to do it myself right now.  Anyone else is welcome to [fork the repo](https://github.com/hbrobotics/ros_arduino_bridge) and give it whirl.  A good place to start might be the [Turtlebot code](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create/tree/groovy/create_node/src/create_node).

FWIW, I do not use a gyro on [Pi Robot](http://www.pirobot.org/) and I am able to do SLAM and AMCL just fine using wheel odometry alone, albeit with a laser scanner.  If I remember correctly, the original reason to put a gyro on the Create-based TurtleBot was because the wheel odometry was rather unreliable, especially when turning.

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2013-08-02**:
Thanks for the timely response.  I have found that a gyro makes a huge improvement for turning accuracy over wheel odometry, so would really like to incorporate that data.  I tried to add gyro support in the way that Turtlebot does, but got bogged down with the details of  /imu/data and imu/raw.

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2013-08-02**:
I spent many hours going through the nav tutorials and trying to pick apart the Turtlebot code but ultimately failed.  I bought the book ROS by Example, which is excellent, but was disappointed that even that book does not cover using a gyro.

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2013-08-02**:
I see from ros.answers that a lot of people have the same problem trying to get gyro data into a non-create-based version of Turtlebot.

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2013-08-02**:
I could publish the gyro data as the theta component of /odom, that seems straightforward, but I don't know if that will allow me access to the good nav features of Turtlebot, since it means I have to use the "no gyro present" option.  Do you think that would work??

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2013-08-02**:
These were actually just one comment, but had to be broken up due to character limits.